# search 2d array and compare to database in php

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, wamp, mac-address

i have a 2D array that looks like this :

```html
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0024E8D4915C
                [1] => 0026B9AC17A0
                [2] => 080027042B7C
                [3] => 1866DA0EBD4C
                [4] => " "\\&
    O��"
                [6] => 64006A5F5DE0
                [7] => B05ADACE88BC
                [8] => B439D6388380
                [9] => D067E51A3B4F
                [10] => D4BED9C2B47F
                [11] => D4C9EFB500A3
                [12] => "�M��>�"
                [13] => F48E382F5B06
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  25
                [1] =>  25
                [2] =>  25
                [3] =>  25
                [4] =>  25
                [5] =>  25
                [6] =>  25
                [7] =>  25
                [8] =>  0
                [9] =>  25
                [10] =>  25
                [11] =>  25
                [12] =>  25
                [13] =>  25
            )

    )
```

i obtained these by using snmpwalk on my switch.[1]=>Array : is the port number that is associated with the mac addresses above.
i need to compare these mac addresses against the mac addresses saved on the database which is :

```html
    Array
    (
        [0] => 0026B9AC17A0
        [1] => 008064A890B2 
        [2] => 1866DA3440E9
        [3] => 3464A9D5B334 
        [4] => 5C260A4F8B7F 
        [5] => 0050568A6F7B
    )
```

How can i obtain the mac addresses thats not in the database along with the port number corresponding to the mac addresses?
the result would look like this:

```html
mac address:        port number:
[0] => 0024E8D4915C 25
[1] => 080027042B7C 25
[2] => 1866DA0EBD4C 25
[3] => " "\\&       25
    O��"
[4] => 64006A5F5DE0 25
[5] => B05ADACE88BC 25
[6] => B439D6388380 0
[7] => D067E51A3B4F 25
[8] => D4BED9C2B47F 25
[9] => D4C9EFB500A3 25
[10] => "�M��>�" 25
[11] => F48E382F5B06 25
```

Comment: to retrieve the values from the database i use mysql queries : $dbconnect=new mysqli('localhost','root','','name');

$query = $dbconnect->query("SELECT mac FROM mac");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//suppose your array's name is $array

for ($i=0; $i < count($array[0]); $i++) { 
    $res[] = array(
        'mac' => $array[0][$i],
        'port' => $array[1][$i]
    );
}

print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an array that looks like this?

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
      ['mac'] => '0026B9AC17A0',
      ['port'] => 25
  ),
  [1] => Array(
      ['mac'] => '080027042B7C',
      ['port'] => 25
  ),
  [2] => Array(
      ['mac'] => 'B439D6388380',
      ['port'] => 0
  )
  ...
)
```

Comment: How would i go about doing that ?

Comment: It depends on how you retrieve the data from the DB, that's not really clear in you question to be honest.

Comment: i use mysql queries to retrieve them:

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code: [eval.in](https://eval.in/802496). Eventually you can remove the empty ones or the weird chars.

```
<?php

$dbArray = [
        "0026B9AC17A0",
        "008064A890B2", 
        "1866DA3440E9",
        "3464A9D5B334", 
        "5C260A4F8B7F", 
        "0050568A6F7B"
];

$resultArray = [
  [
                "0024E8D4915C",
                "0026B9AC17A0",
                "080027042B7C",
                "1866DA0EBD4C",
                "",
                "",
                "64006A5F5DE0",
                "B05ADACE88BC",
                "B439D6388380",
                "D067E51A3B4F",
                "D4BED9C2B47F",
                "D4C9EFB500A3",
                "M000000",
                "F48E382F5B06"
  ],
  [ "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "0", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25"]
];
echo "mac address: \t port number:\n";
foreach($resultArray[0] as $key=> $value){
  if(!in_array($value, $dbArray)){
    echo $value ." \t ". $resultArray[1][$key] ."\n";
  } 
}
```